# How can I know when a Firebase query has ended

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I want to collect the most recent 10 items from my datastore.  I believe I am supposed to do this using `.child()` and `.limitToLast()`, which emits an event every time a result has been added to the child.

I don't necessarily know if there are 10 items in total, so a simple counter won't work.

How do I know when Firebase is finished giving me results?

**Example lookup code:**

```
var plots = [];
firebaseDatastore.child("plots").orderByChild("unicode-timestamp").limitToLast(10).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    // Add the new item to the list
    plots.push(snapshot.val());
});
```

I need to know when the final plot has been added, regardless of whether it has hit the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Firebase query never really ends. It continues to monitor (in your case) the plots by unicode-timestamp and keep a "window" of the last 10 plots.

So:

- child_added:timestamp1
- child_added:timestamp2
- ...
- child_added:timestamp9
- child_added:timestamp10

And then when you add another plot:

- child_removed:timestamp1
- child_added:timestamp11

If you are not looking to use this behavior, you have two options:

1. use a `value` event and then `snapshot.forEach` over the child nodes
2. keep a counter and `off` your listener when you've reached the number of children you expect

Comment: Very helpful to understand Frank, thank you!  in my case the `value` command is what I want.  The counter solution works but will fail if there aren't enough nodes to hit the limit (so I would need TWO queries: one to get the "last" node which I would then treat as an alternative end case, and one to get the list)